# More indepth info while debugging with Xdebug in PHPStorm

Tags: php, debugging, yii, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to analyze what's what in my Yii application by using XDebug paired with PHPStorm. In the "Debug" tool window I can see function calls and the variable list associated with a function call.

There are setting in php.ini that allow xdebug to also collect parameters passed to functions, function return values and also variables that were modified by a particular function.

Is there a way to see all of that in PHPStorm?

Answer (score 1):

The "collect_params" and "collect_returns" extra php.ini settings are for function and stack traces. Xdebug doesn't provide information on which variables where modified by which function. There is information on how to turn on tracing at http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace

In PHP Storm, you can easily see the arguments passed to a function by setting a breakpoint on the first line of the function, and inspecting the incoming values. You can also monitor the return value, by setting up a breakpoint at the return statements of the functions that you are interested in. PHP Storm does not allow you to set a break point on a function's entry point and/or exit point - although Xdebug's DBGp protocol does support that: http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php#breakpoints You could file a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard if you want.